# Core Location on simulator & device

Tags: iphone

When testing on simulator i wont get this pop up  "Would you allowed this app to use your current location" ,but while testing on device this message pops up.Does anybody know why it is?

Answer (score 1):

It is because in the Simulator, you are testing your app, and there is no real location data. It only appears on the device for privacy reasons which, of course, don't exist in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can select any location as your current location while testing your app on the simulator,by Selecting the Simulate Location option[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/features/) that lets you do this, but you have to pay for this.

Answer (score 0):

You get this pop up on device because it is related with some privacy, this is some that the SDK does to verify if the user really wants to allow the app to get info about the device location.

On simulator, it doesn't happen only because Apple doesn't want, but I think it should be asked, so we could simulate some behavior when the user doesn't allow the use of the GPS.

Cheers,
VFN

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom location with custom latitude/longitude using GPX file.
GPX is xml format file for adding custom location to location simulate service.

Here is great example : http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html

According this example, you can create and add gpx file easily. GPX file is standardized file type to simulate locations.

GPX file format looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode"> 
    <wpt lat="-00.000000" lon="00.00000">
        <name>London</name>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

After adding this file to xCode, just select Location to this file in Edit Scheme from top left of xCode.

Let me know if another help needed.

Comment: You need to enter the important content from the link here, link only answers risk deletion.