# How can fake current location in iPhone using code

Tags: iphone, sdk, location

I am using corelocation framework. is it possible to fake current location for use in social network applications ? if yes then how ?

Please help.

THank you in advance.

:: Edited ::

I made code for that after surfing some more, it may be change using overriding methods of class CLLocationManager.
code like some bellow :

```
@interface MyHeading : CLHeading
        -(CLLocationDirection) newHeading;
-(CLLocationDirection) new1Heading;
@end

@implementation MyHeading
-(CLLocationDirection) newHeading { return 55; }
-(CLLocationDirection) new1Heading { return 56; }
@end

@implementation CLLocationManager (LF)
- (void)setFLocation {
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:40.778023 longitude:-73.981935];
    [[self delegate] locationManager:self didUpdateToLocation:location fromLocation:nil];

    id heading  = [[MyHeading alloc] init];
    [[self delegate] locationManager:self didUpdateHeading: heading];
}

-(void)startUpdatingHeading {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setFLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)startUpdatingLocation {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setFLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
@end
```

Thank you all for sharing.
Thanks again.

Comment: Lazy. Have you tried anything yourself? Have you done any research?

Comment: @ Ashley, kindly if you know, just help, its not way to talk. I already tired myself. Thank you.

Comment: Agree with Ashley, have a search around the web and SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054843/core-location-on-simulator-device - you're not the first to think about this.

Comment: yes petert, I agree with you, I search around web and found same things but its not working on device, working on simulator only and for that, I asked this question. Thank you to all.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following [framework](https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator) a try.

Comment: Thank you Petert, I checked with this framework, its work in iOS Simulator but not works in Device iPhone 4. So please let me know if you made. Thank you again.